# What is the best way to reduce and merge a collection of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, collections

So I reached a dilemma this week while trying to solve what seemed to be an easy problem, but I was wrong.

Sample code:

```
let arr = [
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 100.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 50.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae4321', cost: 75.00, orders: 1 }
]
```

So the problem was being able to map through the array and merge/sum the values if their unique identifiers match.

Any suggestions?

End result would look something like this:

```js
[
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 150.00, orders: 10 },
  { id: 'ae4321', cost: 75.00, orders: 1 }
]
```

Now of course the real application will not have statically typed ids, but they were written into this example. So please take that into consideration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for grouping and an array for adding the wanted properties.

```js
let array = [{ id: 'ae0123', cost: 100.00, orders: 5 }, { id: 'ae0123', cost: 50.00, orders: 5 }, { id: 'ae4321', cost: 75.00, orders: 1 }],
    result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (r[o.id]) {
            ['cost', 'orders'].forEach(k => r[o.id][k] += o[k]);
        } else {       
            r[o.id] = { ...o };
        }
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: There were a lot of fantastic answers but this one was strong due to the ability to add a grouping of items, as well as allowing for much more flexibility in the amount of fields.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Map` to store objects by `id`, and add the values if it already exists in it:

```js
let arr = [
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 100.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 50.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae4321', cost: 75.00, orders: 1 }
];
let map = {};
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     let item = arr[i];
     if(map[item.id]){
          map[item.id].cost += item.cost;
          map[item.id].orders += item.orders;
     }else{
          map[item.id] = item;
     }
}
console.log(Object.values(map));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array

For each item, if it already exists then add the cost and orders, else add it to the array.

```js
let arr = [
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 100.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 50.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae4321', cost: 75.00, orders: 1 }
]

let newArr = []

arr.forEach(item => {
  let existingItem = newArr.find(x => x.id == item.id);
  if (existingItem != undefined) {
    existingItem.cost += item.cost;
    existingItem.orders += item.orders;
  } else {
    newArr.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 100.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 50.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae4321', cost: 75.00, orders: 1 }
]

let obj={};

arr.forEach(item=>{
  if(obj[item.id]){
    obj[item.id].cost +=item.cost;
    obj[item.id].orders +=item.orders;
  }
  else{
    obj[item.id]=item;
  }
});

const mappedArr=Object.keys(obj).map(key=>obj[key]);

console.log(mappedArr)
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with **reduce** method of Array object, the above mentioned solution of using literal object works as well, but I think for such case, *reduce* makes code more readable and elegant:

```
const arr = [
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 100.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 50.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae4321', cost: 75.00, orders: 1 }
];

const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (!acc[obj.id]) {
    acc[obj.id] = obj;
  } else {
    acc[obj.id].cost += obj.cost;
    acc[obj.id].orders += obj.orders;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log( Object.values(newArr) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you want

```js
let arr = [
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 100.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae0123', cost: 50.00, orders: 5 },
  { id: 'ae4321', cost: 75.00, orders: 1 }
]

let uniq = []
arr.map(x => {
  if(!uniq.includes(x.id)) uniq = [...uniq, x.id]
})

uniq = uniq.map(x => {
  let filtered = arr.filter(y => y.id === x)
  let res = filtered.shift()
  for(const z of filtered) {
    const {cost, orders} = z
    res.cost += cost
    res.orders += orders
  }
  return res
})

console.log(uniq)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let newArr = []

arr.forEach((el, ind) => { 
    let uniqueId = el.id;
    let obj = el;
    let multiple = false;
    arr.forEach((e, i) => {
        if(e.id == uniqueId && ind != i ) {
            el.cost += e.cost;
            el.orders += e.orders;
             multiple = true;
             arr.splice(i,1);
             newArr.push(el)
        }
    });

    if(!multiple){
        newArr.push(obj);
    }

});
```

Tell me if it works, this will create a new array with the objects.